# How can i extract files using custom names with zipfile module from python?

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I want to add suffix to names of my files, for example uuid. How can i extract files using zipfile and pass custom names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ZipFile.open()`](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open) to open a read-only file-like to the file data, then copy it to a write-only file with the correct name using [`shutil.copyfileobj()`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj).

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Extract the files.

Step 2: Rename them.

Comment: I can't, because there is possibility to overwrite other files, which don't have uuid.

Comment: Then check if there are other files before you rename? Unless there are some more complications here I don't really see the problem...

Comment: I don't think I understand your main question. If you want to extract the zip file to some folder and there's a file in said folder that has the same name as one in the zip file, there's going to be a name clash no matter how you extract the files. You can either write the new file yourself, say by `open(<new name>,"wb").write(archive.extract(<old name>))`, or bypass the entire problem by putting each new zip file in a UUID-named directory of its own.